# How to return one row from group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to extract a list of unique customers from a database where some customers are listed more than once. The (almost) duplicate rows exist because customers have been moved from one division to another or because the customers have been registered with another address (or both).

So my challenge is in data that looks something like this:

```
ID   Customer   Division   Address
-----------------------------------
1    A          M          X
1    A          L          X
2    B          N          Y
2    B          N          Z
3    C          P          W
3    C          T          S
```

I want my select statement to return one row for each customer (I dont care which one).

```
ID   Customer   Division   Address
-----------------------------------
1    A          M          X
2    B          N          Y
3    C          P          W
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. I think I need to do a "GROUP BY" the last two columns but I don't know how to get just one row out of it.

I hope someone can help me!

(Yes, I know the problem should be solved at the source but unfortunately that is not possible within any reasonable time-frame...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ID, Customer,Division, Address from 
(
SELECT 
ID, Customer,Division, Address,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY Customer Order by Id) as RN
FROM T
) t1
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much, valex! I think I - almost - understand how it works. The "t1" makes me wonder? What does that do? Is it just a variable to hold the sub select or ?

Comment: @Peter_DK T1 is an alias for the inner subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT
    , Customer CHAR(1)
    , Division CHAR(1)
    , [Address] CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ID, Customer, Division, [Address])
VALUES 
    (1, 'A', 'M', 'X'),
    (1, 'A', 'L', 'X'),
    (2, 'B', 'N', 'Y'),
    (2, 'B', 'N', 'Z'),
    (3, 'C', 'P', 'W'),
    (3, 'C', 'T', 'S')

SELECT t.id
     , t.Customer
     , t.Division
     , t.[Address]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
         , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM @temp
) t
WHERE T.rn = 1

SELECT ID, Customer, Division = MAX(Division), [Address] = MAX([Address])
FROM @temp
GROUP BY ID, Customer
```

Output -

```
id          Customer Division Address
----------- -------- -------- -------
1           A        M        X
2           B        N        Y
3           C        P        W

ID          Customer Division Address
----------- -------- -------- -------
1           A        M        X
2           B        N        Z
3           C        T        W
```